# Survival Analysis: Number of Censored Events in Life Table

Tags: r, survival

I want to construct a life table for some event of interest. See below for an example:

[image]

I'm trying to do this with `survival` R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf.

```
library(survival)
surv <- Surv(veteran$time, veteran$status)
km <- survfit(surv~trt, data = veteran)
summary(km, censored = TRUE)
```

Notice that I specified censored = TRUE. Specifying this option should make the censoring times included in the output.

It prints time, n.risk, n.event, survival, std.err, lower 95% CI, and upper 95% CI. However, it doesn't print n.exit.censored as expected. I'm trying to figure out why it's not printing the a number censored column. I downloaded the latest version of survival package.

```
packageVersion("survival")
```

Prints

```
[1] ‘2.43.3’
```

Is this happening for anyone else?

Answer (score 2):

The n.exit.censored column is only supposed to be in the output for counting process data, and that's not what you offered. See `?summary.survfit`. You could recover the censoring times by looking at the places where `n.events == 0`. The format that you apparently desire (which is more typical of demography or actuarial type of display) is grouped by yearly interval, whereas the `summary.survfit` output is not grouped, but rather reports the exact time of events and censoring.

Looking at the code, I see that even with counting process Surv object, the column still might not be output as documented by the help page, but ratehr it appears that the column would have a name of "censored".